Return task_id with Branch Condition with TaskFlow
About the tasks bellow. I have a branch task (choose_best_model) and I would like to know if it's possible to return 'is_accurate' with the data
@task.branch
  def choose_best_model(accuracy):
    data = "Cool"
    if accuracy > 5:
      return 'is_accurate'
    return 'is_inaccurate'

  @task
  def is_accurate(data):
    pass

  @task
  def is_inaccurate():
    pass


XCOMs are there to exchange data between tasks.
xcom push from branch task and xcom pull from is_accurate task
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/xcoms.html
if you are using branch operator then the return value of the if/else block is the task_id itself. So it's better you use xcoms to pass data between tasks rather than as task callable parameters.
say your task sequence is as below:
get_accuracy >> choose_best_model >> [is_accurate, is_inaccurate]

have the task before choose_best_model return accuracy and then
change your branch task function from this:
def choose_best_model(accuracy):

to this:
def choose_best_model(ti) -> None:
    accuracy = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_accuracy')
    data = "Cool"
    ti.xcom_push(data)
    if accuracy > 5:
      return 'is_accurate'
    return 'is_inaccurate'

  @task
  def is_accurate(**context) -> None:
    ti = context.get('ti')
    data_rcvd = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='choose_best_model')


Hi @subram, thank you for your message. So when i return is_accurate, I would like to pass it the data variable.

@QDex pls see my edited answer above
